# Выходит ошибка mysqli_fetch_array уже не знаю как ее решить

Tags: php, mysql

Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in on line

Comment: я так понимаю у вас нет проблем $db = mysqli_connect ... ?

Comment: Нет ,нету 
Соединение с MySQL установлено!
Информация о сервере: localhost via TCP/IP

Comment: а зачем вы в первый параметр `mysqli_fetch_array($db,$result)` ставите `db`? напишите просто: `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`

Answer (score 1):

Присоединяюсь к выше написавшим и дополняю от себя: У вас там, А - неверные ковычки в запросе. Б - Нет проверки на результат запроса.

```
 function is_user_set($username){
    global $db;
    if (isset($username)) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$username);
        $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM `users` WHERE name='{$username}' LIMIT 1");
        return boolval(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Получилось, спасибо

Comment: Вот только вышло один варнинг

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in 40

Comment: function get_udata($username){
 global $db;
 $res = array();
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$username);
 $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE name=`$username`");
 $arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db,$result);
    if(isset($arr['json'])){
  $res = json_decode($arr['json'], true);
 }
 return $res;
}

Comment: вы читаете текст ошибки? написано - ожидает один параметр, даете 2. Что тут непонятного-то?

Comment: в 10 местах уже написали - не нужно пихать $db где попало - вы продолжаете.

Comment: Все почистил, 1 ошибка только 
Warning mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in 40


function get_udata($username){
 global $db;
 $res = array();
    $username   = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$username);
 $result     = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE name=`{$username}`");
 $arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if(isset($arr['json'])){
  $res = json_decode($arr['json'], true);
 }
 return $res;
}

Comment: кавычки тут есть или опечатка у вас? WHERE name='{$username}'

Comment: вы кавычки ` замените на обычные одинарные ' там, где **значение**, а не имя поля

Answer (score -1):

Ссылка на подключенную базу данных нужна только в запросе. В mysqli_fetch_array - отвечает за извлечение данных. Подробнее тут [mysqli_fetch_array](http://www.php.su/mysqli_fetch_array).

```
  function is_user_set($username){
        global $db;
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$username);
        $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE name=`$username` LIMIT 1");
        return $result && (bool)mysqli_fetch_array($result)
    }
```

Кстати, если Вам нужно узнать, есть ли такой пользователь или нет, достаточно использовать `COUNT(*)` и `mysql_fetch_row.`

```
 function is_user_set($username){
    global $db;

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$username);
    $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE name=`$username` LIMIT 1");
  
    if($result === FALSE){ 
       // Error msg;
       return null;
    }
    $result = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

   return $result[0]>0;
}
```

Comment: Warning  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in17
Warning</b>:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in 5</b><br />
Warning</b>:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in  6
Warning</b>:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in 7
Warning</b>:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in 8</b><br />
Warning</b>:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in 9
Не удалось зарегать

Comment: function make_user($name, $lastname,$username,$chat_id,$time){
   global $db;
    $name =  mysqli_real_escape_string($name); 5строка
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($lastname); 6 строка
    $username =  mysqli_real_escape_string($username); 7строка
    $chat_id  =  mysqli_real_escape_string($chat_id); 8строка
    $date   =  mysqli_real_escape_string($time); 9 строка
    $query  =  "INSERT INTO `users` (name,lastname,username,chat_id,time) VALUES  ('{$name}','{$lastname}','{$username}','{$chat_id}','{$date}')";
    mysqli_query($db,$query) or die("Не удалось зарегать");
}

Comment: Поправил, пробуйте

Comment: Соединение с MySQL установлено!
Информация о сервере: localhost via TCP/IP

<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_row() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in 16

<b>Warning</b>:  Use of undefined constant result - assumed 'result' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) 17

<b>Warning</b>:  Use of undefined constant result - assumed 'result' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in on line 
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given 6
Не удалось зарегать

Comment: Исправил, пробуйте

Comment: не получится) mysqli_fetch_row нужен 1 параметр, у вас 2.

Comment: @Максим Степанов, спасибо, забыл убрать с оригинала =)